# What is a good approach for splitting this string in C#?

Tags: c#, regex, split

I need to split a string in C# that is formatted as follows:

**"(11)123456(14)abc123(18)gt567"**

With the desired result being a string array such as:

- "(11)123456"
- "(14)abc123"
- "(18)gt567"

I'm guessing that a Regular Expression might be involved but that is one of my weak areas.

Comment: What criteria determines where the string should be split? An open parenthesis?

Comment: Why not using the '(' for the split?

Comment: var parts = text.Split('(').Select(p=>"(" + p).ToArray()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 var result = "(11)123456(14)abc123(18)gt567"
            .Split(new string[]{"("}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(i => "(" + i).ToList();
```

Comment: clever answer that performs much better than the RegEx alternatives.

Comment: This worked great for me. The solution @Schlomo had works well also, but since I use Linq and this solution returns a list it gets me there faster. Thanks to everyone for the quick responses. (I love StackOverflow).

Comment: As a sidenote, I made a slight change to eliminate the extra "(" that was being returned as the first element in the list as follows: var result = (11)123456(14)abc123(18)gt567".Split('(').Where(i => i != "").Select(i => "(" + i).ToList();

Comment: @JimK updated my answer, if you want to remove empty strings when split there is a overload method for that.

Comment: @Damith That's even better. Thanks again.

Answer (score 8):

```
var s = "(11)123456(14)abc123(18)gt567";

Regex r = new Regex(@"\(\d+\)\w+");

var matches = r.Matches(s);

string[] array = new string[matches.Count];
for(int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
    array[i] = matches[i].Captures[0].Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
string theString = "(11)123456(14)abc123(18)gt567";

Regex reSplit = new Regex(@"\(\d+\)[^\(]+");
var matches = reSplit.Matches(theString);
```

That will give you a collection of `Match` objects that you can then examine.

To get an array of strings:

```
var splits = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
```

Comment: don't forget that he has some alpha characters in the second and third matches.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex along with its [`Split` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ze12yx1d(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the array of parts.

```
var s = "(11)123456(14)abc123(18)gt567";
var pattern = new Regex(@"(\([^\(]+)");
var components = pattern.Split(s)
```

The pattern matches an left parenthesis followed by any number of characters up until the next left parenthesis.

If you need to deal with whitespace such as new lines, you might need to tweak the pattern [or the RegexOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5845fdz(v=vs.110).aspx) a little.